# Как из массива подставить поочередно все значения в перменую

Tags: php

Не сильно силен в php. Есть у меня строка с функцией exec() и внутри curl запросом на bash в котором один параметр задан как переменная которую нужно подставлять.

Есть массив с списком IP, поочередно нужно подставлять каждый ип из массива в переменную которая указана в запросе exec()

какую функцию нужно использовать? вроде бы foreach циклично передает значения массива, но внутри foreach выполняю exec() но в нее значения не подставляеются

```
<?php

$ip="";
$pool='4';

$ipmgr='curl -k -s "https://example.com/ipmgr?authinfo=admin:yiuyiut&out=text&elid=127.0.0.1%2F24&elname=127.0.0.1%2F24&func=net.addr" | grep "status=2\|status=7\|status=3" |  grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"';
$vmmgr='curl -s -X POST https://example.net/api/ip/v3/ipnet/4/ip -H "Cookie:ses6=32-8e28d265-49ad-4ac0-92de-e888d9c829e5" -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: 32-8e28d265-49ad-4ac0-92de-e888d9c829e5" -H "alication/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\":\"'.$ip.'\",\"domain\":\"example.com\",\"status\":\"special\",\"note\":\"Some usage info\",\"ippool\":"'.$pool.'"}"';


$arr=exec($ipmgr, $data);

foreach ($data as $ip) {
exec($vmmgr);

}

?>
```

Я хочу из массива взять каждое значение и подставить его в готовую строку переменной $vmmgr в переменную $ip, я не прошу готовый код, подскажите что делаю не так. спасибо

Comment: код то свой приведите

Comment: вообще ехес и баш можно исключить, наверное, а курл запрос выполнить средсвами пхп, или вообще заменить на file_get_contents

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.